# CSS and JS not working in HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, css, https

css and js are working perfectly over http://isdhh.org/ but not on https://isdhh.org/. I'm new to web designing and javascript, and for the life of me cannot figure out how to fix this. The online solutions like, linking CSS file with "//isdhh.org/css/style.css" doesn't fix this. And I cannot understand this protocol relative URL thing described on various websites.

Comment: As anneb said, it's due to mixed content in the page. Next time, check the browser console - mine gives me a bunch of errors along the lines of "Blocked loading mixed active content "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"" which make this issue *really* obvious.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 3):

A page being served in https should not load resources from http.
In your page there are several http resources, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Change all http references to https and try again

Comment: Simpler to just remove protocol and use protocol relative paths

Comment: @charlietfl I believe ref="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn... etc" does not work on all browsers that support bootstrap

Comment: not sure why...is very common practice. Never seen one myself that doesn't

Comment: hmm, I think you're right: it is a problem on IE6 and some issues on IE7/8, but who wants support for that? I think I ran into this problem on Cordova for older versions of Android where the protocol is file://

Comment: I well remember fighting with IE6 and earlier. html5 is a far cry from those days thank goodness

Comment: Thank you anneb anc charlietfl for the suggestions. And what about my custom css and js files? How do I link them? Thanks!

Comment: if your custom css and js files are on the same server, use relative paths like so href="css/my.css" or href="/css/my.css". If they need to be on another server, you have to use https on that other server.

Answer (score 0):

every css, js and image files needs to be served with https://. your bootstrap files are not getting served.

remove the http: from these too
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Thank you Joel, do I replace http with https in these two? And what about my custom css and js files? How do I link them? Thanks!

Comment: @TWyPGn your custom css and js are already good to go because you removed the http/https protocol. that's what you'll want to do with the bootstrap links. make them look like: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.c...

Comment: https files can be used on non-http sites, so you can also modify the links to look like https://maxcdn... instead of //maxcdn... you shouldn't support both http and non-http versions of your site. have all non-https traffic redirect to the secure version of the site

Comment: Thanks Joel for the additional info. Will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

checking the browser console, it seems you requested for bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js over http not https

Comment: Thanks a lot Simeon; does that mean I replace http with https while linking bootstrap files?

Answer (score 0):

The layout and design work perfectly by replacing http with https in bootstrap css and js files. Thank you all for pointing that out. Linking bootstrap files by deleting http/https protocols doesn't work for me. However, there are two websites now: one with http and the other with https. How can I force the browser to show only https? Thank you!